# GiftedChat - Warining 'keyboardShouldPersistTabs={true}' is deprecated. use 'keyboardShouldpersist='always' instead

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In android emulator when i try to run the GiftedChat. it shows Warining 'keyboardShouldPersistTabs={true}' is deprecated. use 'keyboardShouldpersist='always' instead. the typeing input is hiding.

could you please tell me where to modify or am i using wrong version of GiftedChat. how to remove this error. thanks

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please Do update the gifted chat. Latest Version 0.1.3 has the changes which resolves the above issue.